# Excel Checkboxes and Arrays

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, activex

I am creating a project tracker for the team I work with and I want to copy all the project information for a single project in a single row. Then 2 columns in the row will be "Task Complete" and "Date Completed".

Currently I'm using a Data Validation list to select "Complete" in the task complete cell. When "Complete" is listed, the Date Complete will auto populate with "Today's" date. I'm achieving this with just simple functions in excel.

I've then created VBA code so that a command button is clicked, it will highlight specific cells in the row, copy those cells, paste them in a empty worksheet, then clear the task and date complete cells.

I've gotten most of these features to work but I've hit the roadblock in having excel copy the data in the blank work sheet in empty rows only (Row A1, A2, A3, etc). I am unsure how to have the code copy the data in empty rows. I know it can be achieved some how by using a variable (i) and loops.

My other question was, I originally wanted to use check boxes instead of a validated list but seem to have issues with formatting with the checkboxes. If my row size has to change to fit text, the checkboxes will crowd other cells. Is this just a flaw of forms/activeX in excel or am I missing part of the bigger picture?

I tried using an array to check the "Task Complete" column than individual If statements to add the date. Attached is a sample of my code:

```
Dim pjt As Worksheet
Dim datawks As Worksheet
Dim myBook As Workbook  'define worksheets and workboook
Set myBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set pjt = myBook.Sheets("Project Tracker")
Set datawks = myBook.Sheets("DATA")

Dim tskarray(16) As String
     tskarray(0) = Range("K4")
     tskarray(1) = Range("k5")
     tskarray(2) = Range("k6")
     tskarray(3) = Range("k7")
     tskarray(4) = Range("k8")
     tskarray(5) = Range("k9")
     tskarray(6) = Range("k10")
     tskarray(7) = Range("k11")
     tskarray(8) = Range("k12")
     tskarray(9) = Range("k13")
     tskarray(10) = Range("k14")
     tskarray(11) = Range("k15")
     tskarray(12) = Range("k16")
     tskarray(13) = Range("k17")
     tskarray(14) = Range("k18")
     tskarray(15) = Range("k19")
     tskarray(16) = Range("k20")


        If tskarray(0) = "Complete" Then
            Range("A4,B4,D4,F4,G4,J4,L4").Select
            Selection.Copy
            datawks.Select
            datawks.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, skipblanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Sheets("Project Tracker").Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            pjt.Range("J4,K4").Select
            Selection.ClearContents

        Else
        Debug.Print ("No Task to Complete")
        End If
```

Comment: Are you trying to check in cells K4 through K20 for the word "Complete"?

Comment: Take a look to the Range.Offest and Range.End commands. I think they are what you are looking for. Moreover you can also set a range variable instead of using arrays or (more important) instead of selecting the range. You seems like the kind of guy that values self-improvements, so go ahead. If you find any difficulty or prefear a complete example, just say please. I'll be glad to write a code for you complete of notes.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the code copy the data in empty rows"? Btw you can assign a range to an array in a single line.

Comment: @dwirony - Yes checks K4-K20 Complete then fills the cell next to it with the current date.

Comment: @evilbluemonkey Thanks for the tip, I'll definitely look into those commands. I am not against some example code that I can use as reference. I do feel I have an easier time reading code than writing it.

Comment: @SJR sorry for the confusion. I just want to take data from specific cells(a,b,c,d,f,g,j,l) and place that data in a worksheet As new data is entered into that sheet, it's just placed below the last data entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will accomplish your task (at least per your question) incorperating the loops you mentioned.

```
Dim tskarray() As String
ReDim tskarray(0 To 16)
Dim ArrayElementCount As Long
Dim RowCount As Long
RowCount = 3 'this will increment by 1 at the start of the loop so after the last iteration it will end at 16 not 17

For ArrayElementCount = 0 To UBound(tskarray)
    RowCount = RowCount + 1
    tskarray(ArrayElementCount) = pjt.Range("K" & RowCount) 'Assuming on pjt sheet.
Next ArrayElementCount

Dim TargetCell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
RowCount = 3
For ArrayElementCount = 0 To UBound(tskarray)
    RowCount = RowCount + 1
    If tskarray(ArrayElementCount) = "Complete" Then
        For Each TargetCell In pjt.Range("A" & RowCount & ": L" & RowCount) 'Also assuming on pjt sheet
        If TargetCell.Column = 3 Or TargetCell.Column = 5 Or TargetCell.Column = 8 Or TargetCell.Column = 9 Or TargetCell.Column = 11 Then
                'Ignore columns C, E, H, I and K
            Else
                With datawks
                    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    .Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TargetCell.Value
                End With
            End If
        Next TargetCell
        pjt.Range("J" & RowCount & ":K" & RowCount).ClearContents 'Change the column letters if the range should be bigger. 
    Else
        Debug.Print ("No Task to Complete")
    End If
Next ArrayElementCount
```

Comment: That was super helpful. Being able to step through that code and see the results really helped shine some light on how Loops function.

Comment: So I modified the code to apply the TargetCell.Value across the row instead of down the column. I used `.Cells(1, LastCol).Value = TargetCell.Value` to achieve this. I want to then go to the next row like how `.Cells(LastRow, 1).Value` was functioning but only after all of the data from pjt worksheet row is inputed. So for example Row 4 with excluded cells gets input to Row 2 of datawks. Then Row 5 of pjt gets input into Row 3 of datawks.

Comment: If you want it to keep stepping down the rows with each iteration (when necessary) add the last row back in, so `.Cells(LastRow, LastCol).Value = TargetCell.Value`. If you are writing the values along the row and it will *always* be the same length of cells (meaning column G is always the last for example) you can set last row based on that column rather than column A, that way you can still assign it's value in the same place as my code but it won't end up skipping a whole row once you put a value into Column A.

Answer (score 0):

So with the help from everybody on this thread, especially @Samuel Everson and some friends at home, I was able to get my code to work as intended. I wanted to post the working code for advice on improvements or for others that may have similar issues.The code is as follows:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Range


RowCount = 3
ColCount = 3
i = 1
Set j = Range("a1").End(xlDown)

    For ArrayCount = LBound(tskarray) To UBound(tskarray)
        RowCount = RowCount + 1
        ColCount = ColCount + 1

            If tskarray(ArrayCount) = "Complete" Then
                Do While i < 7
                For Each TargetCell In pjt.Range("A" & RowCount & ": L" & RowCount)
                    If TargetCell.Column = 3 Or TargetCell.Column = 5 Or TargetCell.Column = 8 Or TargetCell.Column = 9 Or TargetCell.Column = 11 Then

                    Else

                        With datawks
                         .Range("A1").End(xlUp).Offset(j, i) = TargetCell.Value
                         i = i + 1

                        End With

                    End If

        Next TargetCell
        j = j + 1
        Loop
        i = 1
        'pjt.Range("J" & RowCount & ":K" & RowCount).ClearContents
        End If
        Next ArrayCount
```